# nodejs mongodb perform a different query depending is collection is empty of not

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using mondodb in a nodejs project and I need to check if the collection is empty and depending on the result use and query or another variation.

Here is the code:

```
const { MongoClient, ObjectId } = require('mongodb');
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("lidarDb");

    // This is the part I need help with
    if (mycollection is empty) {
        var myquery = { query variation 1 }
    } else {
        var myquery = { query variation 2 }
    }

    dbo.collection("mycollection").insertOne(myquery, function(err, obj) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if(obj) {
            res.send(true);
        } else {
            res.send(false);
        }

        db.close();

    });
});
```

How can I do this?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking other than basically matching an old question by title. It would be better for you to actually show which two queries you think you need to run. It's very likely when somebody sees your full intent that they can inform you of something better you have not thought of. In 10 years of usage I have never see no need at all to test if a collection has data or not before deciding what query to use

Comment: The other question is not a duplicate as the answer uses count and count is depreciated.

Comment: That's why there are **two** links. And I've already told the person who gave the same response that `count()` is deprecated. Use `countDocuments()`as per the second link. Or perhaps listen to what I originally said and work out that your presumption you need "different queries" is probably incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT :**

*@Neil Lunn is right, and `.count` should **not** be used, since it has been deprecated.*

[.countDocuments](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/) can replace `.count` from version 4.0.3, giving the same results but using an aggregate instead of metadata from the database.

**Original answer :**

**Do not use this, if you want your code to be futureproof**

You can count the documents in a collection using [.count](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/)

```
dbo.collection("mycollection").count({}, (err, count) => {
  if (count === 0) {
    // var myquery = { query variation 1 }
  } else {
    // var myquery = { query variation 2 }
  }
  ...
});
```

Also look into [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), as they make the code look much cleaner.

Comment: Please don't use that method. It was deprecated some time ago. Even if it was the accepted answer on a question with basically the same title.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I missed the deprecation warning. I would delete this answer if it wasn't accepted already.